# Using Django as GUI for long running python process

Tags: python, django, ipc, rpc

This a question about architecture. Say I have a long running process on a server such as machine learning in a middle of a training. Now as this run on external machine I would like to have a tool to quickly see from time to time the results. So I thought the best way would be to have a website which quickly connects to the process for example using RPC to display the results as this allows me to always check in. Now the question is how should Django view gather the information from the server process:

1) Using RPC calls such as rpyc directly in the views?

2) Using some kind of messaging queue such as celery ?

3) Or in a completely different way I am not seeing ?

Comment: This question is too broad for StackOverflow format but the usual practice is to use Celery for asynchronous tasks such as this.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least 2 possible ways to do this.

1. Implement your data-refreshing function as a view and visit it by ajax(sync)+javascript timer.Since you visit your page that contains these js, it will fetch your data silently and update the page. However,this solution does not work well when you need to record all the data in a given frequency;the ajax/view only executes when the web page is open.
2. Use messaging queue like selcuk suggests.Alongside celery, APscheduler is also a good choice because it's easier to install and use.You can implement a task(as modal) queue with status(queue/done/stoped/whatever as field) and check them at the frequency you wanted,save the date you retrieved and do all the other stuff.